# Changes on taxonomy list don't show because of the application cache

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have a spree store in production and every time I add a taxon to the taxon tree, it only shows up in the frontend after I run `bundle exec rake tmp:clear`.

While I would like to maintain the caching in Spree, this shouldn't be the normal behaviour.

I searched in Google but couldn't find any relevant information on the matter.
Searched through Spree preferences and couldn't find any useful information as well.

Summing up, what I would like to know is how can I display the new taxons immediately in the frontend without having to clear the the application cache in the console?

Comment: Which view are you specifically having trouble with? I know that taxons and taxonomies are cached, but I don't know where the entire taxonomy view would be cached in Spree preventing the new taxonomy from being loaded.

Comment: The taxonomy tree in the sidebar. spree/shared/_taxonomies

Comment: That's strange. You can see that the taxonomy itself is cached (https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.2/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_taxonomies.html.erb#L4-L7) but the taxonomies should be loaded from the DB every time (https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.2/frontend/app/controllers/spree/products_controller.rb#L14). Have you made any customizations to these views, or caching in general, which could change the default behaviour in Spree?

Comment: I have an override that substitutes the text "SHOP BY <CATEGORY>" to "<CATEGORY>" in that file, and others that add components to the sidebar, but none that messes with the taxon_tree function. As far as caching, I didn't changed anything

Comment: This problem only happens in staging / production

Comment: Just to clear. You are adding a new taxonomy and not a new taxon?

Comment: No, I meant a new taxon. When I add a new taxonomy it shows immediately on the sidebar. If I add a taxon it doesn't show until the cache is cleared. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67339/discussion-between-gmacdougall-and-nunopolonia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the error with @gmacdougall found out it was a bug in Spree that was causing this problem.

If you're having the same problem you can follow the resolution here:
https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5810